# Are course evaluation forms REALLY confidential?

Tags: ethics, course-evaluation

Someone I know has recently submitted a course evaluation form in which he complained about how poorly the unit was organized and that the lecturer didn't seem to be well prepared for the class. Following the day this course evaluation form was submitted, the lecturer decided to revise the mark he has received for his final project and marked him down. Is this an odd coincidence or are course evaluations not really confidential?

Comment: Short answer? No. But it's unlikely that this lecturer was retaliating. Evaluations take more than a day to process and it doesn't make sense to retaliate anyway.

Comment: Actually, evaluations in many schools don't take any time to "process", because they are collected immediately by the lecturer himself or herself. So it is very reasonable that the lecturer reads them immediately after collection, and "retaliates", so to speak. The lesson is that evaluations should not be a place where students freely rant and humiliate the lecturer.

Comment: @Dilworth the two universities I have experience with make a big deal out of not letting the lecturer see people writing the evaluations and don't get to see the hand-written ones. Students get the form during their exam, where the teacher is not present. When there is no central exam, somebody passes by during the last lecture and the lecturer leaves the room. But yes, I agree wholeheartedly with "evaluations should not be a place where students freely rant and humiliate the lecturer."

Comment: Different universities have different standards and rules. My view is that *allowing students to write anonymous hand-written comments* is an unethical norm that should be abolished. The numeric parts of the questionnaire are fine. But forcing lecturers to read scathing, humiliating, personal remarks against themselves has no ethical or moral basis.

Comment: What, anywhere in the world, in any university? Or perhaps you want to restrict this question somewhat?

Comment: @Dilworth Do you actually have first-hand knowledge of a school which tells students that evaluations are confidential but then the instructor collects them?

Comment: I have first-hand knowledge of schools in which the lecturer collects the evaluations, and the evaluations are anonymous in the sense that students obviously don't write their names on scripts. This is not something exceptional, since evaluations have in many schools no formal role. They are their just to help the lecturer to improve the class. Not to impose measures against professors.

Comment: Indeed, even StrongBad below confirms to be well aware of departments in which the lecturer is responsible for collecting the evaluations.

Comment: My school keeps the evaluations sealed until after grades are "finalized" (they can be changed later, through a challenge, but at that point everything is heavily supervised, so retaliation is unlikely at best) to prevent any lashing out. Even then it's a bad idea to trash-talk the professor; who knows when you'll have them again in the future?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I didn't say he trash talked. As soon as it's written in an appropriate manner every student has to right to express their opinions, which can be good or bad.

Comment: @canberk_gurel Ah, sorry, I wasn't trying to say he did -- just that it's a bad idea, even with anonymous reviews that are held until after grades are turned in, to do so.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I totatlly agree on that.

Comment: The student who wrote the negative evaluation should report this to a department administrator.

Comment: @aparente001, report what? That he/she has a negative opinion about the lecturer? In many cases (I don't know about this case though) this is just an opinion entangled with negative emotions and enjoyment of bashing other people (of authority in particular) while being covered by anonymity. There's nothing concrete to report, for most such cases. I don't suggest disallowing bashing of lecturers. It's completely fine. Just don't expect to get any responses for this, and don't do it on the course evaluation feedback.

Comment: @Dilworth - Sorry I wasn't clear.  The grade change (down), coming on the heels of the scathing evaluation.  None of us knows if that was a coincidence -- only the instructor does -- but the department can certainly ask some questions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Whether evaluations are *anonymous* (see [StrongBad's answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/100689/25112) for the difference with *confidential*, which evaluations are rarely) depends on your institution. On my university, they are. However, especially in small classes you can often get a pretty good idea of who wrote something depending on writing style and typical spelling mistakes.

But as Elizabeth Henning says in the comments, it's unlikely that this is the case here. It takes time before the evaluation is sent to the teacher. On my university, this happens only after all grades have been sent to the administration, after which it is possible to change them, but all those changes are logged - it may even be disallowed to mark someone down in that phase. In any case, the instructor won't care enough about the grade to change it and risk all kinds of trouble.

Answer (score 8):

There is a difference between anonymous and confidential. I have never heard that course evaluations are confidential and I have seen faculty share evaluations. As for being anonymous, I have never seen an evaluation with a space for a name or student number, and the online systems I am familiar with do not make that information available. That said, the feedback, and sometimes writing, often makes it seem like you know who wrote the evaluation.

While you may be able to identify students, many departments try and keep the evaluations sealed until after the grades. Even in departments in which you collect the forms directly from the students, everyone I have talked to recommended not looking at the evaluations until after the grades were submitted.

While there is no benefit for marking a student down for their evaulation, if a faculty member wished to do this, in some cases they could. It would not be unreasonable to go talk to the director of teaching about your perceptions.

Comment: This. If I happen to, say, forget to do a certain class of assignments, then say that that class of assignments should be more heavily noted in class, it wouldn't take a genius to put two and two together, especially in small classes, no matter how anonymous the form itself is.

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on your institution. Mine handled it pretty well: all evaluations had to be submitted electronically  in a centralized system before the final exams to avoid retaliation from students, and were made available to the teachers after the final course grades were submitted to the registrar, to avoid retaliation by the teachers. We received printed results, where all numerical/rating answers were shown as total counts, and verbal answers were anonymized and put in random order. Except for answers citing specific personal interactions, it was impossible for me to make any inference about my students' responses. So at least where I worked, the evaluations were indeed as anonymous as it gets.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that most probably they are **not** strictly confidential nor anonymous. It is in many times easy to spot who wrote what.

Since evaluations in many schools don't take any time to "process", because they are collected immediately by the lecturer himself or herself, it is reasonable that the lecturer reads them immediately after collection, and "retaliates", so to speak.

I would suggest not to write long scathing and hostile rants about the lecturer then.

Comment: As I answered above, different universities have different standards, let alone different countries.

Comment: The comment from @MorganRodgers agrees with how teaching evaluations used to be done in my university, except that I would distribute the blank forms myself and then leave the room while the students filled them out. Nowadays, the evaluations are done on the web, not in the classroom, and I have nothing to do with the process of filling them out or collecting them. In both systems, the evaluation results were made available to me only after I turned in grades.  In the old system, I could sometimes identify students by their handwriting; not so any more.

Comment: Of course, I understand the system is different in different universities. In my case I collect them myself.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Interesting. I was about to ask about whether this was really still done on paper rather than online. Interestingly, where I am (Aarhus), they have recently started having the evaluation just before the course ends, including giving the lecturer access to the results, with the purpose of the lecturer spending 10-15 minutes discussing the results of the evaluation in class with a view towards what sort of changes might be made based on it.